# converting apache http htaccess to nginx config for Prestashop 1.6 multi store

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm running Prestashop 1.6 with multi store enabled. 
Default url is http://192.168.1.217/prestashop161
And I have another shop at this url http://192.168.1.217/prestashop161/shopa

When you change settings, Prestashop creates automatically the htaccess file, however I'm using nginx, and I'm trying to port the config.
Here is what it was generated for me in htacess:

```
#Domain: 192.168.1.217
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192.168.1.217$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/prestashop161/shopa/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and this is what I've tried in nginx:

```
location /prestashop161 {
    root   E:\servers\htdocs;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    rewrite '^/(shopa)$'     /$1/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/api$ /api/ last;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out how to do it based on the official documentation: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/System+Administrator+Guide#SystemAdministratorGuide-NginxfriendlyURLs

This works only if you have Friendly URL enabled, else it will go redirect into an infinite loop.

So here are the steps:

1. Enable Friendly URL
2. Paste this code for main shop

   ```
   location /prestashop161/{
       root   E:\servers\htdocs;
       index /prestashop161/index.php;

       rewrite ^/prestashop161/api/?(.*)$ /prestashop161/webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/c/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/c/$1.jpg last;
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/([0-9]+)(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /prestashop161/img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /prestashop161/index.php?$args;
   }
   ```
3. paste this code for `shopa`

   ```
   location /prestashop161/shopa/ {
       rewrite ^/prestashop161/shopa/(.*)$ /prestashop161/$1 last;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /prestashop161/index.php?$args;
   }
   ```

that's it